# Spring : How to update form elements in a jsp using spring?

Tags: jquery, spring

I have a jsp page with a form. When I enter some value in a text box, those many number of text boxes should come below that initial text box. Say for example, First there is a text box for "NO.Of Units" and when the gives 3 as his/her input, then three text boxes should come below that text box for taking units names for each unit. This should be in a spring page. What is best way to do it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery clone() method and clone a dummy element from your jsp.Something like this:

```
    <script>
    function cloneElement(){
        $("#numberOfUnitsDiv").empty();
        var numberOfUnits=$("#numberOfUnits").val();
        for(i=0;i<numberOfUnits;i++){
        $("#dummyInput").clone().attr('id','unit'+i).appendTo("#numberOfUnitsDiv");
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="numberOfUnits">
    <input type="button" onclick="cloneElement();" value="Proceed">
    <div id="numberOfUnitsDiv"></div>
    <div style=visibility:hidden>
    <input type="text" id="dummyInput">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

For more on clone() method refer :http://api.jquery.com/clone/